# How to override the == operator

Tags: c#, operators, operator-overloading

How can I define the operator `==` for instances of my class? I tried like this:

```
public bool operator == (Vector anotherVector)
{
    return this.CompareTo(anotherVector) == 1 ;              
}
```

but it says:

> overloadable unary operator expected

Comment: Operators must be static.

Answer (score 9):

You need to mark the method as `static` and also you have to implement not equal `!=`.

```
public static bool operator ==(Vector currentVector,Vector anotherVector)
{
    return currentVector.CompareTo(anotherVector) == 1 ;              
}
```

You have to implement `==` for two objects.

AND for `!=`

AND

```
public static bool operator !=(Vector currentVector,Vector anotherVector)
{
    return !(currentVector.CompareTo(anotherVector) == 1) ;
}
```

See: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Overloaded operator == implementations should not throw exceptions.
>   Any type that overloads operator == should also overload operator !=.

Comment: `static` functions can't use `this`.

Comment: Surely `this` in the question was meant to indicate the left operand.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I am fine with the downvote and deserve on this one for missing `this`. But I was more concerned about `static` and implementing `!=`

Comment: Perhaps a nitpick, but I would suggest implementing `!=` in terms of `==`. That is `return !(a == b);`

Comment: @JimMischel, yes that makes more sense

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C++, which allows operators to be defined as instance member functions so that the left operand becomes the `this` pointer, C# operator overloading is always done as static member functions.

There can be no `this` pointer, and both operands are explicit parameters.

```
public static bool operator==(Vector left, Vector right)
{
    return left.CompareTo(right) == 1;              
}
```

(Although this seems semantically incorrect, normally `CompareTo` returns zero for equivalence)

Comment: And how then I call the comparison?

Comment: @user2128702: That part is just like C++.  If you have two vectors `a` and `b`, write `if (a == b)` or `bool same = (a == b);`

Comment: +1 "Semantically incorrect." Yeah. Although come to think of it he should override `Equals(Vector)`, and implement `==` in terms of that. That is `return left.Equals(right)`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree fully with Habib's answer - also +1 it... just don't forget to handle nulls.

```
public static bool operator ==(Vector left, Vector right)
        {
            if ((object)left == null)
                return (object)left == null;

            if ((object)right == null)
                return false;

            return ...;
        }
```

too big to post as his comment. Hope this helps.